# NameError when creating class dynamically

Tags: python

I'm creating a class at runtime in Python, which works just fine:

```
  new_class = type("clazz", (object,), {})
  globals()["clazz"] = new_class

  testobject = clazz()
```

However, when I try to outsource the functionality to a different class, it fails:

```
class ClassFactory:

    @classmethod
    def spawn_class(name):
        new_class = type(name, (object,), {})
        globals()[name] = new_class
        return new_class()
```

Then, in a different class:

```
ClassFactory.spawn(name="clazz")
testclass = clazz()
```

The error message is that "clazz" is not defined. I'm assuming this is because clazz is spawned in a different module, but even when I import everything from that module via

```
from modules.datahandler.config.class_factory import *
```

the error message persists.

Comment: Each module has its own separate global namespace.  And doing `from X import *` only imports the names that existed in the module at that moment in time, it doesn't magically give you any names that are defined later.

Comment: @jasonharper: Yes, in hindsight it was a bit silly to assume that it would import a dynamically created type. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Really, you should just do `clazz = ClassFactory.spawn(name='clazz')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following defined in config_factory.py (note that the `classmethod` should have the class as the first arg)

```
class ClassFactory:
    @classmethod
    def spawn_class(cls, name):
        new_class = type(name, (object,), {})
        globals()[name] = new_class
        return new_class()
```

You should be able to create "clazz" method dynamically, but it would be  available in the module class_factory. So you have to import it to use it

```
>>> from class_factory import ClassFactory
>>> ClassFactory.spawn_class(name="clazz")
<class_factory.clazz object at 0x7f5ad5f2f2d0>
>>> 
>>> from class_factory import clazz
>>> testclass = clazz()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you probably want is a `staticmethod` decorator, not a `classmethod` decorator. `classmethod` implicitly passes a class object to your method

```
class ClassFactory:
     @staticmethod
     def spawn_class(name):
         new_class = type(name, (object,), {})
         globals()[name] = new_class         
         return new_class()
```

Then in a different module, import `ClassFactory` and you should be able to do this

```
Classfactory.spawn_new(name="clazz")
testclass = clazz()
```